# Difficulty with functions - C

Tags: c, function

I am trying to write a function that checks for a certain number and if it finds that number it adds it to the total.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void unitSum(int input[], int output, int unit)
{     
   for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++)
   {
      if(input[n] == unit)  
         output = output + unit;
   }
} 

int main (void)
{
    int array[5];
   int total = 0;

   for(int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
   {
    scanf("%d", &array[a]);
   }

   unitSum(array, total, 1);

 /*for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++)
   {
      if(array[n] == 1) 
         total = total + 1;
   }*/

    printf("%d", total);
}
```

If I run this program with the input '1 1 1 2 2' I get an output of 0. However if I uncomment the FOR loop at the bottom, and comment out the function call. The output becomes 3 (which I want).

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: The problem is that your function `unitSum` does not change the `output` value. You should call `unitSum(array, &total, 1)` instead of `unitSum(array, total, 1)` in the `main`.

Comment: So I if I want to edit values of a variable outside of the function I must put an ampersand before the variable name? EDIT- that didn't fix it

Comment: Yes for sure. Just adding an ampersand won't fix the problem. You have to have a further look about `pointers` to see how it works.

Answer (score 5):

in `C`, parameters are passed by **values**, not by reference, that means that your function makes a **copy** of your variable `output` and processing only with the copy, so it will not change the original. So if you want a function to change one of his parameters not locally, you have to pass a **pointer** to it.
In your code, that will fix:

```
// int *output is the pointer to an int variable
void unitSum(int input[], int *output, int unit)
{     
    for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
        if(input[n] == unit)  
            // here you change the value of the variable that is 
            // located in this address in memory
            (*output) = (*output) + unit;
    }
} 

// ...

// &total is the pointer to variable total
unitSum(array, &total, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your calling function line unitSum(array, total, 1);

to total=unitSum(array,total,1); and in your function unitSum change the

return type to int and return output after closing the for loop.It will be

solved.

```
int unitSum(int input[], int output, int unit)
{     
   for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++)
   {
      if(input[n] == unit)  
      output = output + unit;
   }
   return output;
 }
```

Happy coding.